# Excel ComboBox/formcontrol source cell address

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, cell

I create a ComboBox Dropdown list from selected cells by VBA. How do I get the address (example A1) of selected list item (list items source cell) by VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Here goes... This is one of those obscure things. The `ListFillRange` property here is for the `OLEObject` embedded in the `Shape("Drop Down 1")`

```
Sub FillComboRange()

    Dim Cb As Object
    Set Cb = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Drop Down 1").OLEFormat.Object
    Cb.ListFillRange = "D16:N30"
    Set Cb = Nothing
End Sub
```

and if you need the range string, just do:

```
Sub GetComboRange()

    Dim Cb As Object, Str as String
    Set Cb = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Drop Down 1").OLEFormat.Object
    Str = Cb.ListFillRange

    MsgBox(Str)

    Set Cb = Nothing
End Sub
```

For the selected Cell in particular, the address can be given by `Cb.LinkedCell` and shading options are given by `Cb.Display3DShading`

Comment: I ment that I allready have a range where to select list items. I dont have to declare it. I need to return an address to a selected item. Cell address where this item has been taken into the list.

Comment: yeah, then simply declare some string and get `Str = Cb.ListFillRange`

Comment: Hi, I will get empthy msgBox/Strig

Comment: Hi. The tricky part about this question is to figure out the ole object. Once that's done please try to modify the code with a bit of effort to suit your program. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Note: I’ve organized this code for the sake of explaining things, **not** as an example of best practices.

```
Function getSourceCellAddress(combobox_object as Object) as String

  ' get the name of the source range
    Dim name_of_dropdown_source as String
    name_of_dropdown_source = combobox_object.RowSource
  
  ' get the source range itself
    Dim dropdown_source_range as Range
    Set dropdown_source_range = Range(name_of_dropdown_source)
  
  ' get the current selected value
    Dim current_selected_value as String
    current_selected_value = combobox_object.Value

  ' get where in the list the selected item is located
    Dim row_index as Long
  ' two possible routes here: remove the one you don't need
    index = combobox_object.ListIndex ' if source doesn't have a heading row
    index = combobox_object.ListIndex + 1 ' if source has a heading row

  ' get name of source worksheet
    Dim worksheet_name as String
    worksheet_name = dropdown_source_range.Parent.name

  ' get the cell reference for the source data
    Dim address as String
    address = dropdown_source_range.Cells(row_index, 1).Address

  ' add the worksheet name and return the value
    getSourceCellAddress = worksheet_name & "!" & address
End Function
```

You can use this function in situations like, `getSourceCellAddress(Table_Name.combobox_id)`.